# PowerShell command to connect to Exchange from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I have the following command to connect to Exchange PowerShell. I use C# to connect, however the last line, `Import-PSSession $Session`, makes the site crash and takes me to the debugger.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force mypassword;$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist me@mail.net,$password;$LiveCred = Get-Credential -Credential $mycred;$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlookurlforpowershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection; Import-PSSession $Session
```

Here is my C# code:

```
private void initconnection(string text){

    Runspace rs = GetRunspace();
    Pipeline cmd = rs.CreatePipeline(text);
    Collection<PSObject> results = cmd.Invoke();
}

initconnection("$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force Maxipereyra15;$mycred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist cpereyra@crescentmortgage.net,$password;$LiveCred = Get-Credential -Credential $mycred;$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection; Import-PSSession $Session");
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: are you saying the ps command works in a command window but not through c#?

Comment: is there a resdon you are calling powershell from c# and not using the exchage API?  also which version of exchange?

Comment: muratgu that is correct if I type the same commands into powershell it works fine.  However through c# it doesn't. Stuart haven't looked into exchange api, does it have the same command as powershell?

Comment: have you tried stepping through the code and see what exception it generates?

Comment: cmcletinvocationexception is the exception it throws.  There were errors in loading the format data file: 
Microsoft.PowerShell

Comment: I believe the issue is that I am trying to run a script but do not have administrative privileges, and when I try to run the command to run scripts it tells me the registry value can't be changed.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, and have not found a solution. The reason for not using the exchange API is because operations-dept already had a powershell script in place.